# name of current item in listbox

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, listbox

for example, i have a simple database (int id, string text) and listbox.
in each listbox element i have a textblock, image and button.

when I add items I want each item listobox was known as the id.
When I click the button, the id is passed in another form in which I can edit the database post.

page.xaml

```
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                            <Image Source="{Binding IconSource}"/>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
                                <Button Click="Edit_Click1"></Button>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

page.xaml.cs

```
    private void Edit_Click1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int id = 0; // i want to know id of current element of listbox
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/EditTask.xaml?currentID="+id, UriKind.Relative));

    }
```

how i can name current item of listbox and then know name of this element? sorry for horrible english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `listbox.SelectedItem` to get the selected item:

```
private void Edit_Click1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int id = (listbox.SelectedItem as MyClass).Id; 
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/EditTask.xaml?currentID="+id, UriKind.Relative));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var button = ((System.Windows.Controls.Button)sender);
        var clickedItem = (DataItem)button.DataContext;
        MessageBox.Show(clickedItem.Name);
    }
```

Here I'm asuming DataItem is the name of the class that represents each item.